# Fire Jquery function when element has .focus

Tags: jquery

I have a this function which fires the .cascade function when a form dropdown box has focus, this works ok but it only works the first time the page is loaded.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#country_select').focus(function() {
$('#country_select').cascade();
});
});
```

So when you click back on the element to give it focus the function does not run...

How do I code this so that it will run each time someone clicks the element or the element has focus..?

I can use any event handler i just need the .cascade function to run if the #country_select element is clicked on...?

Any ideas...?

Many thanks

Comment: this should work fine. what does cascade do?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you want to bind on `change` instead of `focus` to have `.cascade()` be ran each time the country is changed, not focused.

Comment: cascade populates another dropdown based on your selection see: http://www.host-wordpress.co.uk/  select a country..? thanks

Comment: @Phil ok what should the code look like to achieve this...?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $('#country_select').change(function() { $(this).cascade(); }); });`

Comment: @Phil no joy I'm afraid http://www.host-wordpress.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source for jquery-cascade, I believe it isn't being used properly. There is no need to bind it to a focus or as an event handler to the select. It handles binding event handlers to the parent select itself.

The following should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#country_select').cascade();
});
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply - you are absolutely right well spotted ..! - I should have explained that the .cascade function is conflicting with a jquery  menu the cascade function strips the menu of the dropdown indicators ie. > , so  I'm trying to hack this by only calling the function when the filter menu is selected...? hope this makes sense...? thanks